# How do I pass values to an non-command line executable with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have an executable that accepts typed user input on three seperate lines on the GUI. The executable also has a button called "create file" that will perform a file creation based on the typed data. My question is how can I automate passing the three typed values into the executable and then execute the "create file" button all from a batch file? I do not have access to the source code so I cannot make modifications there to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

(Im not able to write comments yet, so I have to use an "answer")

I agree Cebence, as far as I know you need some kind of macro player. Best free I know of is autohotkey (just google for it). It needs a bit reading in at first but is pretty easy to use and very versatile.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not really a batch file solution - I don't think one exists.  But you could use a tool like Spy++ to find the IDs of the relevant dialog controls and then write a program to:

1. Launch the executable
2. Retrieve the main window handle
3. Send the appropriate window messages

There is probably software out there that can do this.  Maybe there's something that you can batch which will just take the process name or ID and pass a single message to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the GUI application doesn't support command-line arguments BAT file will not be of much help here.

What you actually need is some kind of "GUI macro player" application that will execute a script, i.e. macro like this one:

1. Switch focus to running application named "XYZ"
2. Find the input box named "text1" and type in "${param1}"
3. Find the input box named "text2" and type in "${param2}"
4. Find the input box named "text3" and type in "${param3}"
5. Find the button named "button" and click it.

I don't know if there are (free) applications that can do this now, but there was a free application called "Act!" or something like it (its icon was a yellow Mickey Mouse glove with a finger pushing a button). It was actually a ZIP file containing a running Windows executable and Delphi application source code, but I can't find it now on PC Magazine's website.

Hope this helps.